# Date calculations - how to use today's date if date not specified

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a question regarding Microsoft Access 2010. I'm working on an inherited complaints database and I've been asked to produce a report outlining how long complaints have/ or were active.

Using the following I'm able to calculate the difference between when a complaint was opened and when it was closed and show the number of days active.

```
DaysActive: DateDiff("d",[COMPLAINTS]![DateRcvd],[COMPLAINTS]![DateClosed])
```

My issue is when a complaint hasn't been closed I don't get a value returned. Is there a way to modify the expression so that if the DateClosed is empty it will use the current date instead?

Comment: yes you are correct. I have changed it in my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a query expression, the db engine supports the `Date()` function which returns today's date.  So you can use an `IIf` expression to give you `Date()` when `DateClosed` is Null, or otherwise `DateClosed`

```vb
DateDiff("d", COMPLAINTS.DateRcvd, IIf(COMPLAINTS.DateClosed Is Null, Date(), COMPLAINTS.DateClosed))
```

If the query will always be run from within an Access session, you can use  `Nz` instead of `IIf` ...

```vb
DateDiff("d", COMPLAINTS.DateRcvd, Nz(COMPLAINTS.DateClosed, Date()))
```

Note that `Nz` is a VBA function and `IIf` is supported directly by the db engine, so `IIf` should theoretically be faster .  But the difference may not be perceptible in your context.

Comment: Redoing it for when DateClosed is null, which is what I meant to type originally I get this      DateDiff("d", IIf(COMPLAINTS.DateClosed Is Null, Date(), COMPLAINTS.DateClosed), COMPLAINTS.DateRcvd)

Comment: I revised the answer, but my new version is different than yours.  I thought you want to compute the duration from `DateRcvd` to `DateClosed`  Also I didn't have enough parentheses in the original version.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
DaysActive: DateDiff("d",Nz(COMPLAINTS.DateRcvd, Date()),[COMPLAINTS]![DateClosed])
```

`Nz` will check if the date is available or not, if not , it will replace today's date for that, using `DATE()` function.